# Shopping Cart Price Rule - cart totals equal to or greater than w/ a equal to or less than subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I'm attempting to create a shopping cart price rule with custom discounts based on cart subtotal.
E.g.
Less than $10k = 2%
Between $10k and $25k = 3%
Between $25k and $35k = 4%
Greater than $35k = 5%

Example for 3% rule:
Adding the subtotal condition below does not work.
[image]

Any guidance would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of solution here.
[image]

Provides specific discount based on the carts value.